# find more than one value of average on list python

Tags: python

There is a list on python that i want to try to find the average of each value in [],there is 3 value in each [] and i want to find the average of it,so how is it?

```
[[8.07, 8.06, 8.07], [8.27, 8.34, 8.32], [8.64, 8.98, 8.8], [9.27, 9.29, 9.3], [9.52, 9.58, 9.52], [9.69, 9.7, 9.05], [10.19, 10.16, 10.17], [10.46, 10.49, 10.48], [10.85, 10.84, 10.96], [11.04, 11.06, 11.1], [7.91, 7.93, 7.93], [8.5, 8.55, 8.46], [8.99, 8.84, 8.96], [9.53, 9.3, 9.53], [9.69, 9.66, 9.68], [9.81, 9.84, 9.87], [10.41, 10.45, 10.43], [10.59, 10.67, 10.65], [10.98, 11.04, 10.04], [11.09, 11.3, 11.29]]
```

how to find value on each[]?

Comment: Seems like homework. What have you tried? Where are you stuck? Hint: `sum([8.07, 8.06, 8.07])/3` is the average of the first one.

Answer (score 2):

For an array containing each averages:

```
averages = [len(arr)]
for arr in myArray:
     averages.append(sum(arr) / len(arr))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following methods:

#### np.mean()

```
>>> numbers = [
    [8.07,8.06,8.07],[8.27,8.34,8.32],[8.64,8.98,8.80],[9.27,9.29,9.30],[9.52,9.58,9.52],[9.69,9.7,9.05],[10.19,10.16,10.17],[10.46,10.49,10.48],[10.85,10.84,10.96],[11.04,11.06,11.10],
    [7.91,7.93,7.93],[8.50,8.55,8.46],[8.99,8.84,8.96],[9.53,9.30,9.53],[9.69,9.66,9.68],[9.81,9.84,9.87],[10.41,10.45,10.43],[10.59,10.67,10.65],[10.98,11.04,10.04],[11.09,11.30,11.29]
]
>>> import numpy as np
>>> [np.array(nums).mean() for nums in numbers]
[8.066666666666668, 8.31, 8.806666666666667, 9.286666666666667, 9.540000000000001, 9.48, 10.173333333333334, 10.476666666666668, 10.883333333333333, 11.066666666666668, 7.923333333333333, 8.503333333333334, 8.93, 9.453333333333333, 9.676666666666668, 9.839999999999998, 10.43, 10.636666666666665, 10.686666666666667, 11.226666666666667]
```

#### List Comprehension

```
>>> [sum(nums) / len(nums) for nums in numbers]
[8.066666666666668, 8.31, 8.806666666666667, 9.286666666666667, 9.540000000000001, 9.48, 10.173333333333334, 10.476666666666668, 10.883333333333333, 11.066666666666668, 7.923333333333333, 8.503333333333334, 8.93, 9.453333333333333, 9.676666666666668, 9.839999999999998, 10.43, 10.636666666666665, 10.686666666666667, 11.226666666666667]
```

Or if you need to round them to 2 decimal places you can make use of `round()`:

```
>>> [round(sum(nums) / len(nums),2) for nums in a]
[8.07, 8.31, 8.81, 9.29, 9.54, 9.48, 10.17, 10.48, 10.88, 11.07, 7.92, 8.5, 8.93, 9.45, 9.68, 9.84, 10.43, 10.64, 10.69, 11.23]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution:

```py
data = [[8.07, 8.06, 8.07], [8.27, 8.34, 8.32],..., [11.09, 11.3, 11.29]]
averages = []
for items in data:
    averages.append(sum(items)/len(items))
```

Note that, by using `len(items)` in the denominator rather than just `3`, you do not have to explicitly specify the length of each list, allowing this method to work for lists of lists with many different numbers of values.

This can also be simplified using list comprehension:

```py
data = [...]
averages = [sum(i)/len(i) for i in data]
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
def find_avg(lst: list) -> list:
    return [(sum(l) / len(l)) if l else float("nan") for l in lst]

result = find_avg(my_list)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use statistics.mean()

```
from statistics import mean

data = [[8.07, 8.06, 8.07], [8.27, 8.34, 8.32], [8.64, 8.98, 8.8], [9.27, 9.29,
                                                              9.3], [9.52, 9.58, 9.52], [9.69, 9.7, 9.05], [10.19, 10.16, 10.17], [10.46, 10.49, 10.48], [10.85, 10.84, 10.96], [11.04, 11.06, 11.1], [7.91, 7.93, 7.93], [8.5, 8.55, 8.46], [8.99, 8.84, 8.96], [9.53, 9.3, 9.53], [9.69, 9.66, 9.68], [9.81, 9.84, 9.87], [10.41, 10.45, 10.43], [10.59, 10.67, 10.65], [10.98, 11.04, 10.04], [11.09, 11.3, 11.29]]

for n in data :
    print(n)
    print(mean(n))
```